# Переменная в SQL запросе

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Как в SQL запросе (имя БД) вcтавить  переменную?

```
$id_ales = 1234;
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $id_ales (id, type) VALUES ('$id_chold', '$type')");
```

Comment: @Zow, вы не пробовали книжки почитать? У вас очень банальные вопросы, которые говорят о том, что вы даже не пытались учиться.

Comment: спасибо за комплимент) ответ знаешь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $id_ales = 1234;
/*1*/ $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$id_ales` (`id`, `type`) VALUES ('$id_chold', '$type')");
/*2*/ $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `".$id_ales."` (`id`, `type`) VALUES ('".$id_chold."', '".$type."')");
/*3*/ $result = mysql_query('INSERT INTO `'.$id_ales.'` (`id`, `type`) VALUES ("'.$id_chold.'", "'.$type.'")');
/*4*/ $result = mysql_query(sprintf('INSERT INTO `%s` (`id`, `type`) VALUES ("%s", "%s")',$id_ales,$id_chold,$type));
```

не надо огрызаться. [[@Sh4dow](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow) правильно сказал. Работа со строками описана во всех книжках по PHP

Comment: я не согласен) не во всех

Comment: Автор, название, издательство / пруфлинк. Хоть повеселимся, что ли. Единственное, что я могу допустить, если условиться, что книжка нормальная, что она написана для крутейших профи, которые уже знают как работать со строками. Но вряд ли такую можно легко купить=)

Comment: PHP5 for Dumies

Comment: @Zow, не знаю, как вам и сказать, но обратите внимание на страницы 81-91 (если у вас действительно англоязычное издание). На этих 11 страницах изложена глава "Working with Character Strings".

Answer (score 2):

По-хорошему: во-первых, цифровое имя для таблицы (,то что у вас в запросе - не БД) - это плохо. А так читайте про конкатенацию и вообще строки в php.

```
$id_chold = intval($id_chold); // цифровое значение
$type = mysql_real_escape_string($type); // строковое значение
$result = mysql_query('INSERT INTO ' . $id_ales . ' (`id`, `type`) VALUES (\''  . $id_chold . '\', \'' . $type . '\')');
```

Если привыкнете писать так - у вас не будет проблем ни со вставкой переменных, ни с другими языками, ни с безопасностью в запросах.

Comment: А почему использовано экранирование кавычек, а не просто другой тип? Читабельность же выше...

Comment: Так да, не знаю, у меня неприязнь к двойным кавычкам именно потому, что PHP их парсить пытается) Ну и просто на всякий случай - если человек умудрился строку в кавычки вообще не обрамить (один из прошлых вопросов), то про экранирование ему тем более полезно узнать.

Comment: ну, PHP-то пытается, но остальные-то нет.

     print('<a href="mylink.php">спам-ссылка</a>');

Нормально, вроде.
А насчет полезно узнать... @Prikol 'ов тут много, это да...

Answer (score 0):

Мой вам совет - переходите на PDO.